# How to get two level parent directory in window and linux batch file

Tags: linux, windows, batch-file, command

How do I the two level parent directory of the specific files in windows batch cmd and in Linux file?

for example:

> C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\my\this.bat **in window**
>
> \opt\home\this\my\this.sh **in linux**

When run this above batch file, I want to get C:\Oracle\Middleware\ (parent of parent directory  of this batch file)

I wirtten the below in window but only can get the first parent folder:

```
set CURRENT_DIR=%cd%
cd %~dp0\..
set PARENT_DIR=%cd%
echo %PARENT_DIR%
```

Answer (score 0):

for WINDOWS:

just do another `cd..`:

```
cd %~dp0 &cd.. &cd.. &echo %cd%
```

You can also try this:

```
cd %~dp0\..\..
```

but I don't know, if this works on all windows versions.

Answer (score 0):

For windows

```
for %%f in ("%cd%\..\..") do set "secondParentFolder=%%~ff"
echo %secondParentFolder%
```

Use a relative path in a `for` command to be able to get an absolute path

For linux maybe something like this could work (not tested)

```
secondParentFolder="$(cd ../../; pwd)"
```